# get user information using twitter api on android app

Tags: android, twitter4j

is there a way to get the @name of twitter's account using this libray `twitter4j-4.0.2`?

thanks in advance.

Comment: You're looking for getScreenName, but it's an async call.

Comment: also getName is async call.

Comment: You can getName async from the cached user IIRC, screen name always hits the network.